# Select query doesn't return the first row from the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two table joined by a certain order_id, it selects from table number 2 based on table 1. Its working but not selecting the first row of table 2 for example below its return **id** 6 and 7 leaving 5 whereas they share the same order_id
Table2 structure
[image]

[image: Table 2 example]

Here is the result
[image: Query Result]

Is it my code or its something esle i cant seem to figure out?
I am testing this on XAMPP
below is my php code

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
}
$conn = $pdo->open();
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, invoice_address.id as invaid, invoice.id as invid FROM invoice_address LEFT JOIN invoice ON invoice.order_id=invoice_address.invoice_no WHERE invoice_address.id= :id");
    $stmt->execute(['id' =>$id]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = '.......'.$e->getMessage();
}
    
foreach($stmt as $row){
    $output .= '<tr>
        <td>'.$row["item_name"].'</td>
        <td><small>'.$row["item_no"].'</small></td>
        <td>'.$row["qty"].'</td>
        <td>R '.$row["price"].'</td>
        <td>R '.$row["amount_total"].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: You do not `fetch` the row.

Comment: @MarkusZeller if i do $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) it gives me the same result

Comment: Change to `while($row = $stmt->fetch())`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller they do

Comment: @MarkusZeller No change!

Comment: `ON invoice.order_id = invoice_address.invoice_no` -> `ON invoice.order_id = invoice_address.order_id` ?

Comment: Check the query itself in a DBMS. I think the JOIN is improper. Show us the table structure, please.

Comment: Have added an image of the table structure

Comment: @YourCommonSense OMG! PDOStatement extends an iterator interface. And all the years I used manual fetch calls :)